# How to filter homepage posts by popularity?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, homepage

I want my WordPress homepage to display post by popularity. Like it automatically bring the post to top which have been visited by most visitors and same in ascending order.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: And do you already have any code that calculates the popularity of posts?

Answer (score 1):

First thing we need to do is create a function that will detect post views count and store it as a custom field for each post. To do this, paste the following codes in your theme’s functions.php file

```
function wpb_set_post_views($postID) {
    $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
//To keep the count accurate, lets get rid of prefetching
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

Now that you have this function in place, we need to call this function on the single post pages. This way the function knows exactly which post gets the credit for the views. To do this, you would need to paste the following code inside your single post loop:

```
wpb_set_post_views(get_the_ID());
```

If you are using a child theme or you just want to make things easy for yourself, then you should simply add the tracker in your header by using wp_head hook. So paste the following code in your theme’s functions.php file

```
function wpb_track_post_views ($post_id) {
    if ( !is_single() ) return;
    if ( empty ( $post_id) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;    
    }
    wpb_set_post_views($post_id);
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpb_track_post_views');
```

Once you have placed this, every time a user visits the post, the custom field will be updated.

Note: If you are using a caching plugin, this technique will NOT work by default. We are using W3 Total Cache, and it has the feature called Fragmented Caching. You can use that to make this work just fine. Here is what needs to be changed:

```
<!-- mfunc wpb_set_post_views($post_id); --><!-- /mfunc -->
```

Now, you can do all sort of cool stuff such as display post view count, or sort posts by view count. Lets take a look at how to do some of these cool things.

If you want to display the post view count on your single post pages (often next to the comment count or something). Then the first thing you need to do is add the following in your theme’s functions.php file

```
function wpb_get_post_views($postID){
    $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
```

Then inside your post loop add the following code:

```
wpb_get_post_views(get_the_ID());
```

If you want to sort the posts by view count, then you can do so easily by using the the wp_query post_meta parameter. The most basic example loop query would look like this:

```
<?php 
$popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC'  ) );
while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();

the_title();

endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: I have already read this answer on an original site from where you have copied it.

Comment: @Ayu If it's not sufficient then you should explain why in your original question. Otherwise you're just wasting people's time.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I am sorry i just forgot checking this thread.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get popular posts, there must be a certain parameter to decide popularity of the post. Some of the parameters on which the post popularity can be known are post likes, post views, and the number of comments.

According to me "**Post Views**" seem appropriate parameter for deciding popularity of the post.

Step 1: Create a custom post meta to store post views. Add below code in **functions.php** to add additional post meta field **"post_views_count"**.

```
<?php
// function to display number of posts.
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}

// function to count views.
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
?>
```

Step 2: Now we need to store views every time user visits posts single page. Add below code in your **single.php** file to count the number of post views every time user visits post single page.

```
<?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

Also, use below code to display post views on the **single.php** page, so that we can check of the sort order of posts on listing page is as per post views of that particular post.

```
<?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

Now randomly visit few posts pages and check the value of post views. If post views increase every time you refresh your page then it is working correctly.

Now we can use the value of post meta **"post_views_count"** to calculate the popularity of the post. Higher the count of post views means more popular is the post. So change the sort order of posts in default WordPress blog page template (**home.php**) by adding below code in your **functions.php** file.

```
<?php
// Function to change order of Post
function wpdocs_five_posts_on_homepage( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set('meta_key', 'post_views_count');
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpdocs_five_posts_on_homepage' );
?>
```